# What does Robert C. Martin mean here regarding seldom using mocking tools?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

What does Robert C. Martin mean here regarding seldom using mocking tools?

Reference:

https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/05/05/TestDefinitions.html

I don't agree with the article he's criticising (never unit test), but I do understand the primary complaint: That unit tests mean laborious refactoring when you add "collaborators" (I'm inferring this as meaning dependencies) to a class.

Robert C. Martin states that he rarely uses mocking tools. I agree that mocked dependencies can be a pain to update for failing unit tests as the system grows. But what's the alternative? He suggests writing his own 'test doubles' (mocks), with the implication that the cost of doing so deters him from writing code in such a way that it would need them.

That's great if those dependencies were some how not needed. But how are they not?

When writing code to favour composition over inheritance and using dependency injection, mocks become a useful and seemingly essential part of unit (or micro) testing.

I hate that unit tests make my code brittle, but I've always assumed that that's just the associated cost of the benefits that tests can provide.

Am I missing something with regard to coding style that would allow me to maintain loosely coupled code but avoid brittle code around "collaborators"? I'm familiar with Kent Beck's work and had felt I had a strong grasp of TDD but this article makes me wonder if there's something I could be doing better.

Comment: This probably opinion based. People might agree or not. My interpretation / approach is as follows: When you *facade* all external libraries, all dependencies are yours, so you can re-implement their interfaces (in worst case: subclass) and use the simple implementation. Then complex mocking would only be needed in the facades... In reallity, working with legacy code, mocking is usefull to bring old code under test in the first place...

Comment: Agree that could be an interpretation, but they're still mocks. The 'collaborators' are still mocked out and so we're still always 'micro testing' by the articles definitions. And why / how is it better to write your own test doubles than use a library like Moq that helps you set up a test double as required on a per test basis? Could he be suggesting that centralising the test double makes it easier to update tests when the collaborator interface changes?

Comment: **My** understanding is, that it is considered to be much simpler to have a really plain mock object, instead of a complex mocking library. But, as said, I too think that mocks *are usefull*. At some point you need to provide something that fullfills the minimal dependency requirements. If the object isn't super simple itself, use a mock. The only thing I really see here is: Mocking can be much simpler that setting up a complex system of sub-dependencies etc. (been there, done that). Clean code would allow you to write much simpler tests. So testing isn't the issue: The code is.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've found my way to Martin Fowlers article here, which clears up a lot of my questions. https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I have come to understand these comments as steering a developer to using either real implementation objects or 'Test Doubles' over Mocks where possible.

This facilitates testing state where mocks require that we test behaviour. Trade offs include it being time consuming to set up reusable 'Test Double' object hierarchies where code is not well designed (when modifying legacy code), where mocks are easy to set up once, but tend to be set up many times for many tests, which is where code can become brittle.

Martin Fowlers article here helps with further understanding.

https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html